# Select element to show from an JSON array in an ng-model

Tags: json, angularjs

I have a JSON object that have (inside) an array of objects. I want to show one (the active one) in an input, and the others in a list of spans (or divs, or labels, don't care).

The element looks like this:

```
[{
    name:"myName",
    age: "myAge",
    items:[
        {
            itemName:"someName1",
            itemIsActive:false
        },
        {
            itemName:"someName2",
            itemIsActive:true
        },
        {
            itemName:"someName3",
            itemIsActive:false
        },
    ]
}]
```

The items array size is uncertain (can even be empty).

And the result I'm trying to get is this one:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="{{here goes the active one}}">

<span>{{here goes the first that is not active}}</span>
<span>{{here goes the next that is not active}}</span>
<span>{{and so on}}</span>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, one way to do it would be the following.

HTML template

```
<div ng-repeat="current in data">
  <div ng-repeat="item in current.items">
    {{ item.itemName }}
    <input 
      type="radio" 
      ng-value="item"
      ng-model="$parent.currentItem" />
  </div>

  <hr />

  <div ng-show="currentItem"> 
    <input ng-model="currentItem.itemName" />
    <div ng-repeat="current in data">
      <ul>
        <li 
          ng-repeat="item in current.items" 
          ng-show="item !== currentItem">
            {{ item.itemName }}
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

[image: imgur]

---

Related plunker here http://plnkr.co/edit/M8y1vQ

Comment: Hello, sorry, this somehow is a workaround of the problem but not what i'm looking for. We end up solving the problem from the backend (witch we don't want to, for maintenance reasons).
Anyway, i'll mark this as the correct answer because it lead us to some testing that point it out a flaw in the js aproach we took. Cheers.